# Deleting Mail from gmail account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I am able to send mails with attachments to multiple users using c# code. I want to delete the sent mail which  have sent from my gmail account using c#. Is there a way to do it.

My code for sending mail with attachment.

```
if (MailID1 != null)
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            try
            {
                mailidcount = MailID1.Split(',').Count();
                mailids = new string[mailidcount];
                mailids = MailID1.Split(',');
                var Adminmail = "User@gmail.com";
                var AdminPassword = "password123!";
                var AdminSmtpclient = "smtp.gmail.com"
                string sub = Formobj["Subject_Text"]+" " + Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                mail.Subject = sub;
                mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Adminmail);
                mail.To.Add(mailids[0]);
                if (mailidcount > 0)
                {
                    for (int a = 1; a < mailidcount; a++)
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(mailids[a]);
                    }
                }
                mail.Body = "<pre>" +Formobj["Message_Text"] +"</pre>";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                string filename;
                string Filename = Path.GetFileName(Infile.FileName);
                filename = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Content\\TrialFolder\\Filefolder\\" + Filename);
                if (Infile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Infile.SaveAs(filename);
                    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attached;
                    attached = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filename);
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attached);
                }
                if (sub != null)
                {
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(AdminSmtpclient);
                    smtp.Host = AdminSmtpclient;
                    smtp.Port = "587";
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Adminmail, AdminPassword);
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename) == true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            mail.Attachments.Dispose();
                            System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
                            mail.Dispose();
                            smtp.Dispose();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
                        }
                    }
                    TempData["EmailMessage"] = "Your Message has been sent Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["EmailMessage"] = "Please check Email Settings";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an entire API for gmail => https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs

Comment: Thank you So much, but if I am using mail accounts other than gmail, then what is the solution

Comment: If your client account uses IMAP then you could write/use a library as a client (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6) Otherwise you are dependant on an API, If the protocol is exchange for example you will have to find information about exchange. It really depends on the protocol how you can delete/find messages.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Third party dll's like `OpenPOP,IMAP4` you can use them to delete the sent mail.The `SMTP` is used only for `sending mails`